# howto use transactions in SQLite with C# and System.Data.SQLite library?

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions, transactionscope

I am using the System.Data.SQLite library (version 1.0.83.0) and C# 4.0 to use a SQLite database.

I would like to use a transaction and I am trying to do the following:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
{
        EntitiesSQLite myContext = new EntitiesSQLite();

        string strSQLSongDB = "select * from Songs where IDSong = 38";
        Songs mySongDB = myContext.Songs.SqlQuery(strSQLSongDB).FirstOrDefault<Songs>();

        string strSQLAuthors = "select * from Authors";
        List<Authors> lstAuthors = myContext.Authors.SqlQuery(strSQLAuthors).ToList<Authors>();

        scope.Complete();
}
```

I can get the song, and the pass to the next line, when I set the strSQLAuthors, but when I try to get the authors in the next line, the application wait about 10 seconds until I have got the error "underlying provider error open".

When I get the song, and pass to the next line, I try to use an external application (SQLite expert) to search for songs, but the song 38 is showed so the transaction does not block the register, that is what I want when I want to use the transaction.

I don't have problems using the context in other cases, when I don't use transactions, but in this case I don't know kow to block register to not be able to be readed by other user if other user has read the register.

For business logic, I need to ensure that I load all the data for some operations, and I need to ensure that it is not created other new registers that has relation with the data to process.

I would like to know how is the best way to use transactions with SQLite and C#.

Comment: You must read more about [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

Comment: You don't need to create any transaction when reading.